# Dated-fns can't parse ISO Date

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-fns

Using 2.0.0-beta.4 of date-fns I'm stuggling to figure out the format string for parsing and ISO date. My date string is as follows:

> 2019-08-31T14:36:28.511Z

And the parsing code is as follows:

```
parse(v, 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date());
```

v here is the string and this doesn't parse. I've also tried the following:

```
parse(v, 'yyyy-MM-dd[T]hh:mm:ss.SSSZ', new Date());
```

This also doesn't parse as I get 'Invalid Date' returned for all of these. This problem is actually in a third party library that I'm using so I can't change it from using the parse rather than parseISO function.

Comment: You can pass that ISO string directly to `new Date(isoString)`

Comment: Can you show full code? Because it does work on their official documentation in console.

Comment: I'll create a repro sorry I should have in the original

Answer (score 4):

`parse` expects date string (first argument) to match the format (second argument) in an exact manner.

In your case, it should be this,

```
parse("2019-08-31T14:36:28.511Z", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", new Date())
```

Please refer [parse documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.1/docs/parse) to form the correct format string.

Here is the working example, https://codesandbox.io/s/date-fns-playground-forked-t7mvqe?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer:

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';

format(new Date(v), 'yyyy-MM-dd'); // or another desired format
```

Comment: That's not a good idea for iOS (MacOS) + Safari.

Comment: What's the difference between DD and dd. Also why does mm give wrong value. There is confusion around uppercase and lowercase

Comment: @SteveTomlin The difference (based on the [docs](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format)) is that `dd` represents the day of month, *e.g.*, `01`, `02`, ..., `31` whereas `DD` represents the day of year, *e.g.*, `01`, `02`, ..., `366`. Pay attention to the left-padded zeros because using `d` and `D` will not have any zero-padding.